# How to get only a finite number of entries using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I am using slice method in the code example below after getting a whole bunch of data from an API. Is there any method to query just a finite number of entries from API without loading bundle of JSON Data?

```js
getDataBtn = document.getElementById("getData");
box  = document.getElementById("container")

getDataBtn.addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData(){
    url = "https://api.github.com/users";
    fetch(url).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        
        //getting first five items only
        var myArray = data.slice(0,5).map((item)=>{
            x = { ID : item.id , Username : item.login , Github_URL : item.html_url } ;
            return res;
        })
        box.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    })
}
```

Comment: If there is, it's a function of the API and would be documented in the API - e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users#list-users states the default number of users is 30, but you can get up to 100, and presumably less than 30 if you want - side note, the default, 30, is `a finite number`

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can read about additional query parameters for the above mentioned API - [link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users#list-users)

```
function getData(){
    url = "https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5";
    fetch(url).then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        box.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: Can I ask how to get results from second page? I tried `https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5&page=2` but it keeps displaying results from page 1

Comment: @GrafiCode, you can get the 2nd page by doing a HTTP GET - [https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5&since=5](https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5&since=5) and similarly, 3rd page - [https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5&since=10](https://api.github.com/users?per_page=5&since=10). Notice the since property and per_page relationship. For nth page, `since=n*(per_page)`